# Knockout - write a value to a ko.computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've built a very data/number heavy app in Knockout. I'm currently getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you
>   specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't
>   pass any parameters.

This is happening when my custom bindingHandler (which formats the numbers into 'large' form, ie. 123,345,678,987) tries to write back to the original input which displays the value of a computed function.

**Value displayed in an input element:**

```
self.value = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.chosenAge().population; // 'fetched' from an array.
});
```

**Binding Handler:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.largeNumber = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        numberInit(element);
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var interceptor = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                // inject number formatting
                return numeral(ko.unwrap(value)).format('0,0');
            },
            write: function(newValue) {
                // remove formatting when writing a new value
                value(numeral().unformat(newValue));
            }
        });
        // display new value in target element
        if(element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                value: interceptor
            });
        }
        else {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                text: interceptor
            }); 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you really want to write back to your `value` computed? Or you want to update the  `population`?

Comment: Basically as you can tell the value that displays in the input field is fetched from the chosenAge array. I'm trying to get it so if you click into that input element you can enter your own custom population WITH the `largeNumber` formatting

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify a 'write' option in your ko.computed function. Please see the [documentation on computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). Your binding handler has nothing to do with your value failing to update. Your computed should look something like this:

```
self.value = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.chosenAge().population; // 'fetched' from an array.
    },
    write: function (value) {
        //update your self.chosenAge().population value here
    },
    owner: self
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I tried this originally, the issue I'm having is with writing it back? Not sure how to go about it

Comment: Without some more information about your `chosenAge` object I can't really give you a good answer, could you update your post with more information on it?

Comment: I think your code is incorrect, inside `ko.computed` should be an object, not a function. Also the link is outdated, the new link is http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html

Comment: this is not even proper javascript

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would capture the implementation of your formatting in an `extender`.

Define an extension that wraps the data observable with a `computed` formatter:

```
ko.extenders.largeNumber = function (target, option) {

  var formatter = ko.computed( {
    read: function(){
    var formatted = target().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return formatted;
  },
    write: function(nv){
        var numeric = nv.replace(/,/g,""); 
        target(numeric);

        console.log("View model now contains " + target())
  }
 })
 return formatter;
};
```

Then create an observable that uses the extension: (I've wrapped it in a constructor)

```
function createExtendedObs(initialValue){
    return ko.observable(initialValue).extend({
    largeNumber: {
        viewModel: self
    }
 });
```

In addition, I would make my observable be the `population` property within the data object that represents a `chosenAge`

```
{
  name: "Bronze",
  population: createExtendedObs(10000)
}
```

*This is not a requirement.* If you want the population to be stored in another observable, I setup the extender to have access to the viewModel through the `options` parameter. Thus, you would access the other observable that way. If the "other" observable were to be a computed, then you would need to specify the `write` function (*as depicted in the other answer*) which is the root of the issue you are having. Another option would be to `subscribe` to `chosenAge` and set the "other" population observable from within the subscription.

Using the data property directly, I am able to bind to it as follows,

```
<div data-bind='with: chosenAge'>  
  <input data-bind='value: population'></input>
</div>
```

Check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/QBge4/) for the full setup.

---

**Edit**

Just reviewed a comment about wanting to enter the value "with" the formatting. The field will be formatted each time the computed receives a new value. By default, this will be on focus loss. If you want to modify it as the input is provided then you would need to provide the `valueUpdate` binding parameter. *Since the field is being manipulated dynamically this will cause caret positioning issues*. You would need to manage the caret position accordingly.

```
<input data-bind='value: population, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'></input>
```