# How to pass a parameter to a computed function in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is actually a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117681/how-can-i-pass-the-current-element-to-a-javascript-function-in-a-knockout-js-bin/27117738#27117738) that I asked earlier.

I needed to pass an element to a function to check if one of its children had a checked checkbox, and I got that working (described in the question above), but the answer given does not make any allowances for the checkbox to be observed. How would I go about detecting a change in a child element when my Knockout Binding is on a parent?

I cannot pass a parameter to `ko.computed` as I am told:

`Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option`

Any ideas?

Comment: This link might help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062330/knockout-write-a-value-to-a-ko-computed

Comment: You're going about this wrong. See nemesv's comment to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) article:

```
var _innerValue = 0;
var computedValue = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            // you can put here some additional logic
            return _innerValue;
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            // you can put here some additional logic
            _innerValue = newValue;
        }
    });
```

If you don't need any specific logic, you can use simple [ko.observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).